# When define python async function, what happens and how it works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters, async-await

Look the following code:

```py
import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())  # THIS LINE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Look at `# THIS LINE`, asyncio.gather can do its functionality before its parameter count() return value.

But as my understanding toward python. The python interpreter consider the outer function to be a black box and focus on evaluate its parameter first. When all value of its parameter done, the interpreter then pass it to the function to execute.

According to my understanding above, there will be no difference between:

```py
await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())
```

and

```py
await (count(), count(), count())
```

The later one is a non-assigned tuple.

But how `asyncio.gather` implement its jobs in such a form?

Or there is something special for async function definition itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function `count` is defined as `async def count():`, when calling it - instead of executing the function, it returns a coroutine object.

A coroutine (such as `count`) starts executing only when using `await` on it.
The way the expression `await count()` is evaluated is as following:

1. count is called, returning a coroutine.
2. `await` starts waiting on the coroutine.
3. the coroutine executes, returning `None` (because the function `count` returns nothing)
4. the expression `await count()` returns `None`.

So, to your example - when executing `await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())`:

1. `count` is called three times, returning 3 different coroutines.
2. These coroutines are passed as parameters to `asyncio.gather`.
3. `asyncio.gather` itself returns a coroutine.
4. `await` is waiting on `asyncio.gather`, which awaits on all its parameter coroutines.

The second expression, `await (count(), count(), count())` won't work, as you can't use `await` on something which is not a coroutine.

Comment: If the coroutine is launched as a task, it can start executing even if `await` is not called on it (control would have to return to the event loop, but not necessarily because the task got `await`ed). `gather` happens to schedule any coroutines passed *as* tasks, which is why all three of them can be dispatched simultaneously (if it didn't make them tasks, it would just be beginning and `await`ing each in sequence, they couldn't operate concurrently like this code does, with all three sleeping concurrently).